# Attempting to unpack a non-sequencepylint(unpacking-non-sequence) with pyproj transform

Tags: python, list, numpy, pylint, pyproj

I have some code that runs the pyproj transform function:

```
        webm_to_wgs84_transformer = Transformer.from_crs(CRS("epsg:3857"), CRS("epsg:4326"))

        lats, lons = webm_to_wgs84_transformer.transform(
            np_array_x.tolist(), np_array_y.tolist()
        )
```

However, I get the pylint error on `webm_to_wgs84_transformer.transform()`:

```
Attempting to unpack a non-sequencepylint(unpacking-non-sequence)
```

I looked at the docs at given a list of xx and yys it should produce a `Tuple[Any,Any]`, so it should be a sequence, yet I get the pylint error. Anyone know why this is and how to fix this?

Comment: why this: [pylint can't handle @overload](https://github.com/PyCQA/astroid/issues/1015). How to fix this: # pylint: disable=unpacking-non-sequence